# Eclipse IDE does not fill elements and attributes in sample XML file

Tags: xml, eclipse, testing, schema, dtd

I'm trying to generate XML file starting from a DTD schema for testing purpose.
I've read different solution but this one seems to be the simpler and for sure free.
The problem is the tool correctly generate the XML file but "forget" to fill the elements and attributes with data so to be quite useless.

There is a particular reason for this behavior? There is a sort of fix?
Here attach my DTD file.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT booklist ( book+ )>
<!ELEMENT book ( title, author+, section+ )>
<!ELEMENT section ( title, ( paragraph | figure | section )* )>
<!ATTLIST section id ID #IMPLIED difficulty CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ELEMENT figure ( title, image )>
<!ATTLIST figure width CDATA #REQUIRED height CDATA #REQUIRED >
<!ELEMENT image EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST image source CDATA #REQUIRED >
```

[setting up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XykuO.jpg)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBEtb.png)

Answer (score 0):

You probably needed to check those boxes for the optional elements and attributes.

Comment: It doesn't work anyway. Is it possible to be a bug for the Eclipse version i'm running? My version is: 2019-12 (4.14.0)

Comment: You also appear to have not defined what the title and author elements are, and more.

Comment: The DTD above is unchanged. I can't see what you tried.